# Get a querystring from URL and pass as querystring to new URL using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to Get a querystring from URL1 then redirect to URL2 - with the querystring from URL1 appended.

The querystring has 2 values:

```
http://URL1.com/hi/j?a=123&b=666
```

I want this to redirect to:

```
http://URL2.com/hi/b?a=123&b=666
```

I can't find anything on doing this on Google. I found this but it only works with 1 value and seems to have got criticism - and it only takes the querystring and doesn't add it: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this pattern `\?(.*)` . Match the regex pattern after `?` .Then paste with newly created url extenstion

**Add your code as like this**

```
var a =window.location.href;
var after =/\?(.*)/g.exec(a)[0]
window.location.href='http://URL2.com/hi/b'+after
```

**Working example**

```js
var a ='http://URL1.com/hi/j?a=123&b=666';
var after =/\?(.*)/g.exec(a);
console.log(after[1].split('&'))//try with your wish from array(selectquery)
console.log('http://URL2.com/hi/b'+after[0])//for whole query
```

Comment: thanks - any chance of making it do the redirection on page load javascript isn't my strong point thanks :)

Comment: great thanks - just one more thing, - can you add a variation that only has 1 querystring value, thx.

Comment: I was added with snippet. create the array with all query string .You could chose with respected one